πάντες (pantes) translated as many/most?
In

Romans3:23 “for all have sinned and fallen short of the glory of God"

the Greek word πάντες (pantes) is used and translated to all. Has the Greek word πάντες (pantes) (All in English) ever been translated as most or many in other verses?

Not that I am aware.  The Greek word for "many" would be πολύς (pollus) as in Rom 5:15-19.

I know that "all" is sometimes used when a majority is meant. Like when John the Baptist was baptizing in the Jordan River the scripture says ALL of Jerusalem came to see him. It is used like that in other places too I just can't remember them.

One issue you have with translating πάντες as 'most' in Romans 3:23 is that it would then clearly suggest that there are some that have met the standard of "the glory of God."  If that were true, we'd notice.  The utter, wondrous splendor of God is a pretty high bar.  Though, come to think of it, if someone met that bar by being "the express image of God", we'd probably crucify him.

πᾶς and its forms are never translated most in the New Testament.
In the case of Matt. 3:5 and Luke 5:17, it refers to every surrounding geographical region, not all the people.  Mark 1:5 is similar but not as clear.  To say that Paul literally didn't mean all is a matter of interpretation, not translation.  One would be saying that Paul was using hyperbole, and a proper translation would keep the figure of speech intact.
Here is how πᾶς, πᾶσα, πᾶν gen. παντός, πάσης, παντός is translated by the ESV in the New Testament (generated with Logos Bible Software).

Here are the sense of the word. Each is singular, all is plural.   πάντες is nominative masculine plural.

Here are the Greek works translated most by the ESV in the New Testament.


Good comments! One must be careful about imposing a modernistic precision on words that could be more of a hyperbole or having a meaning of "all sorts." The Biola scholar, Kenneth Berding, has a helpful article, "Does 'All' Mean 'Every Sing One' in the Bible?" https://www.biola.edu/blogs/good-book-blog/2023/does-all-always-mean-every-single-one-in-the-bible-romans-11-26
